# Set defaults values power Designer

Tags: designer

I am creating a physical model with power designer and I would like to add default values ​​to my Mysql table.

It is possible?, Someone added default values​​?

thanks

Answer (score 9):

It is possible, wasn't easy for me to discover the "column properties"
here is how:

- Select the table (one click)
- Wait 1 second
- select the column (another click)
- Alt+enter (or right click-> properties)

Now you are editing the column properties, under the 'standard checks' tab you will find the default field.

Hope it helps